# How to get the type of a property by name using generics

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

I need a way to get the type of any property of a class or a type.

For example if I had the `PersonClass` and `PersonType` I want to get the `nationalId` type. I can do this:

```
class PersonClass{
    name: string
    nationalId: number
}

type PersonalType={
    name: string
    nationalId: string
}

type GetNationalIdType<T> = T extends {nationalId: infer U} ? U : never;
var nId3: GetNationalIdType<PersonClass>
var nId4: GetNationalIdType<PersonalType>
```

And it works ok `nId3` is a `number` and `nId4` is a `string`. But If I dont know how to do if I want to get any property. I try these:

```
// type GetProp<T, K> = T extends {[key: K]: infer U} ? U : never;
type GetProp<T, K extends string> = T extends {[key: K]: infer U} ? U : never;

var nId1: GetProp<PersonClass, "nationalId">
var nId2: GetProp<PersonalType, "nationalId">
```

And I get:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want [lookup types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types).  If `T` is an object type and `K` is the type of one of its keys (or a union of such keys), then `T[K]` is the type of the value for that key (or the union of the value types for those keys):

```
var nId1: PersonClass["nationalId"]; 
var nId2: PersonalType["nationalId"];
```

If you feel the need to define `GetProp`, it is pretty straightforward without conditional types:

```
type GetProp<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K];
```

or if you must allow `K` that is not assignable to `keyof T`:

```
type GetProp<T, K extends keyof any> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
```

or if you really want to use [`infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) and [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types), you need a mapped type like [`Record`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1439-L1444):

```
type GetProp<T, K extends keyof any> = T extends Record<K, infer V> ? V : never;
```

But really the simple lookup type is the way to go, in my opinion.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the mapped type syntax to do this with conditional types:

```
type GetProp<T, K extends string> = T extends {[key in K]: infer U} ? U : never;
```

But I think you are really looking for a type query :

```
var nId1: PersonClass["nationalId"]
var nId2: PersonalType["nationalId"]
```

Comment: The two answers are accurate. This one adds `[key in K]` to the other.

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer that syntax is the same as the `Record` version @jcalz suggested, his is definitely the best answer :-)